How to read future void function
When i run the code it works terminal but i can't run the code in flutter, which widget should i use for this. can someone help me to display the result in a textbox or in a widget
Future<void> main() async {
  print(await getDrivesOnWindows()); 
}

Future<Iterable<String>> getDrivesOnWindows() async => LineSplitter.split(
        (await Process.run('wmic', ['logicaldisk', 'get', 'caption'],
                stdoutEncoding: const SystemEncoding()))
            .stdout as String)
    .map((string) => string.trim())
    .where((string) => string.isNotEmpty)
    .skip(1);


You can use FutureBuilder widget, it's better to narrowing cast that iterable to list.
 Future<void> main() async {
      print(await getDrivesOnWindows());
    
    runApp(
    MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
      appBar:AppBar(),
      body:FutureBuilder(
        future: getDrivesOnWindows(),
        builder:(context,snapshot){
         if(snapshot.hasData){
        // Your code to display that iterable
       ...... 
     }
         else{
           return CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
    }
   )
  ) 
 )
); 
    }

more info about future builder

Oh god thank you so much. I did not know this widget
